# reset list column width to default in sp 2007

Tags: 2007, list, column

okay so a few weeks ago I adjusted the width of a column in one list and as a result all the lists seem to be reflecting the change (very wide fist column).

I did this by following the instructions below

```
 I think you can modify the width of the column using Microsoft
 SharePoint Designer 2007. The steps below:
 1.    Open the view in Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2007.
 2.    In the "Design" window, right click anywhere on the body of the view.
 3.    Select "Convert to XSLT Data View".
 4.    Click once on the column title you wish to adjust.
 5.    You should now be able to drag the column to the desired width
```

But 1) I'm unclear on why the change I made to one list is showing up in other lists and 2) how to revert the change

(this is on a hosted sharepoint site so I have limited ability to make back end changes (i can edit files but thats about it)

thanks so much

Comment: Can you right click on the page in SPD and reset it to site definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have a feeling that as you said its taken effect though all list means you might of made the change within allItems.aspx page.

All lists use this aspx page. Now you have changed the size its not automatic anymore!

either do as ybbest said, or:

go into sharepoint designer,

navigate to your list,

under views double click "all items" now it will take you to allitems.aspx;

within the code view look at:

```
<WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart
```

**please copy your code and put it in a text editor before you do any modification! if you need to revert back then just past the code back in and save!**

now goto a nod that starts with `<xsl>` you need to delete everything including and from `<xsl>` to `</xsl>` save and exit.